# Apache Tomcat Server shows taking lot of time in ServletRequestListener.requestInitialized

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-restcontroller

Webservice hosted on tomcat apache server, started showing slow response.

On NewRelic it shows the time is spend on ServletRequestListener.requestInitialized() method.

Looks like that is correct as the application timestamps for the request shows request start processing after few seconds and processing completes fast no delay there. this does not happen always. is this because the threads are help up ?

Any help to troubleshoot why would this be happening.

Comment: may be waiting for DB availabilty. as there was a high cpu and i/o with Database

Comment: we found that all 200 http threads were staying active on couple of the servers. These might have caused the new requests in the queue.

Comment: I am seeing same issue in newrelic. Were you able to solve the issue?